# React: use SVG, map or canvas for my app, flickering issue

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg, canvas

Im creating an app of booking seats for the local stadium. There will be thousands of places, and I need to handle displaying them, and handling events, like clicking, disabling. My idea is to have stadium model in figma (or another vector-editing program) with described class and ids for exported elements, then I will render SVG and parse through classes, so I will handle when Im clicking the .seat class etc.

- Are svgs ok with many objects like thousands of circles etc? I will expect nesting and multiple groups.
- Is this approach ok? It needs to be zoomable, scalable, responsible.
- another solution could be just a html map with mapped coordinates, but mapping thousands of places seems like hell.
- If im sticking to my svg approach, I want the parent container, which has seats below it, to disappear, when Im hovering on it. Im triggering just "display: none" when Im hovering on specific class -> but the svg starts to flickering instead. That's where my doubts have started.

Cheers!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "flickering". Does the specific class apply to part of the SVG or is it somewhere outside of the SVG?

Comment: it's part of the svg, one of nodes. Flickering means when I move mouse inside the rectangle, it quickly appears and disappears.

Comment: Without a [reprex] ppl on SO can only guess...

Comment: Hmm my question is mainly focused on choosing the correct tool for that. About flickering example, Its just svg rendered in React and edited via styled components. Inside, there is `#container-class:hover { display: none }` and hovering causes blinking, dont know why.

Comment: Anything with `:hover { display: none }` can be expected to be flickering, though.. Because when your mouse goes over the element, the element disappears. Then when the element disappears, the element is "nowhere in the page", so the mouse is technically not over the element. Since it no longer counts as ":hover", after the next refresh, the "display:none" does not apply anymore, so the element re-appears . Then, unless the mouse position is moved away (or there are some other changes in the document), the mouse pointer is again over the element. The cycle repeats.